# Disable Windows 8 Monitor detection with display port monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have 3 [Dell UltraSharp U2414H](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=860-BBCG)  Monitors connected to a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 980 graphics card via display port. The monitors are not chained. So each monitor is connected directly to the graphics card. I'm running the latest NVIDIA drivers (344.48).

When I turn one monitor off. Windows 8.1 helpfully re-arranges my desktop down to two monitors. Then down to one when I turn of all the panels.

Is there anyway to stop windows from doing this? Its especially frustrating to have to re-organize my desktop windows every time I turn my monitors off.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fix for this. Someone has decided that this is what you want, so this is what you get. The behaviour is baked into Windows and you cannot override it.

A real deal-breaker for multi-monitor users, this one... you can stick with DVI if you don't need 4K 60fps, I suppose. That's what I do.

Comment: I'd love to switch to dvi except that my monitors don't have dvi in (only display port and hdmi) and my gfx card doesn't have dvi out (only display port and hdmi). Since display port is apparently the future, I guess we are stuck with this crappy mulit monitor implementation for ever now.